# jQuery loading multiple divs simultaneously

Tags: jquery

please tell me if there is a simple answer to this problem I am currently having.

I am building a site with a horizontal nav bar in the middle of the page

The nav bar consists of 6 buttons ("About Us", "Services", Recent Work", "FAQS", "Quote", COntact Us")

I have managed to get the jQuery to load the divs from the html pages into the the div above the nav bar.

As follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#navigation a').click(function() {
      $('#slider').hide();
      $('#slider').load($(this).attr('href')).slideDown(1000);
      return false; 
   }).eq(0).click();
});
```

However in the space BELOW the nav bar I also want to load a different image for each button I click on

For example when I click on the "About US" button the div called #slider will load the #content div from the aboutus.html page into into the #top_slider div which is above the navigation bar, but then I also need the relevant aboutus.jpg to load into the #bottom_slider div which is situated below the nav bar.

So basically for each navigation button clicked, a div above AND below the nav bar slides in simultaneously.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navigation a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent following the link in the browser
    var img_src = $(this).attr('data-img-src');
    $('#slider, #img-holder').hide();
    $('#slider').load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
      // load the image
      $("#img-holder").empty().html($("<img>").attr("src", img_src));
      // show both DIVs
      $("#slider, #img-holder").slideDown(1000);
    });
  }).eq(0).click();
});
```

To use this, add a div `#img-holder` where you want your images to appear. Add the attribute `"data-img-src="/path/to/img.jpg"` to your links in the navigation bar, e.g.

`<a href="about.html" data-img-src="about.jpg">About</a>`

Comment: hmmm interesting but the images are not loading, should the image be wrapped in a html file perhaps?

Comment: Are you able to post a link to your site/code? If not, could you make a jsfiddle example of what you're doing?

Comment: yeah sure I have uploaded the site and it is at www.stewartpaxton.com.au

Comment: Dude you have no <div id="img-holder"> in your HTML!

Comment: Ooops! My bad! However, I've put it back in and it is still not working for some reason...

Comment: Ah, this is my bad! See edited answer - need to read the img_src when $(this) is referring to the link element - inside $('#slider').load it's referring to the slider element, which has no data-img-src attribute :) hope it works this time!

Comment: AWESOME!! Great work Josh, works really well now, thank you for your time and help! :) - Stewart